# MySQL PDO Subquery construct help - Never done this before

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a sub query in MySQL, however I cant seem to get this to work. Ploughed through many posts trying to find a silution. It's all a little over my head. Im hoping this is a simple one for you guys.

```
SELECT * FROM jobs x 
         LEFT JOIN status b on x.id = b.job_id 
         LEFT JOIN delivery d on x.id = d.job_id 
         LEFT JOIN logos h on x.id = h.job_id 
         LEFT JOIN customers c on x.customer_id = c.customer_id
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                    FROM communicator t 
                    WHERE x.id = t.job_id 
                    GROUP BY t.id 
                    DESC 
                    LIMIT 1)
WHERE x.status=1
```

So the problem is the last `LEFT JOIN` where I start a sub query. I cant get it to work. What am I doing wrong? I only want one result from the communicator table the last record added, hence the order by `DESC` limit 1.

Comment: Consider addin a `on` condition for the this last left join.

Comment: Obvious issue: `DESC ` should be `ORDER BY colname DESC`

Comment: leave PHP, PDO out of it. Please post the SQL error you are seeing if any.

Comment: @e4c5 Thats a pretty big edit to the OP's question

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly indeed. But he is just using PDO to execute a static query.  There is no use of PHP other than that. He could have done this just as easily in mysql console or phpmyadmin

Comment: I mean all the information is there, its just a case of formatting it correctly. I have no idea how to format the sub query. After 5 hours of trying different things I still cant achieve the desired result. Im new to this so be kind please.

Comment: Might have been better to get OP to echo out the error message from PDO so next time OP can fix his own bugs

Comment: Looking to you code could you explain the meaning of the subselect .. seems you want the  first row of comunicator table  where job_id = x.id .. but how do think to use this left join ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the 2 normally used types of sub query. When doing a join against a sub query you need to give the sub query an alias name. Further when doing a join against a sub query you wouldn't reference a field from another table in that sub query - rather you would reference such a table in the ON clause.

Something like this I would expect:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs x 
LEFT JOIN status b on x.id = b.job_id 
LEFT JOIN delivery d on x.id = d.job_id 
LEFT JOIN logos h on x.id = h.job_id 
LEFT JOIN customers c on x.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM communicator t 
    GROUP BY t.id 
) sub0
ON x.id = sub0.job_id
WHERE x.status=1
```

However a further issue is that your sub query is doing a GROUP BY t.id, but you are returning the job_id and other fields. Which particular job_id is returned is for an id not defined. How your multiple fields relate and which ones you need I do not know, but I suspect for a start what you would want is something like this, to get the latest id field for a job_id

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs x 
LEFT JOIN status b on x.id = b.job_id 
LEFT JOIN delivery d on x.id = d.job_id 
LEFT JOIN logos h on x.id = h.job_id 
LEFT JOIN customers c on x.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT job_id, MAX(id) AS id
    FROM communicator  
    GROUP BY job_id
) sub0
ON x.id = sub0.job_id
WHERE x.status=1
```

Comment: Thank you for educating me Kickstart. Wow the SQL console in phpmyadmin helped allot, didnt think about pasting queries in there. Thanks again